# Funcion PDO no me funciona bien

Tags: php, pdo

Resulta que tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
$pdo = openPDO();
$pst = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE index_sale SET name = ?, country = ?, province = ?, city = ?, postal = ?, notes = ?, celphone = ?, address = ?, specify = ? WHERE reference = ? AND sign = ?');
$pst = $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pst->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(2, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(3, $department, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(4, $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(5, $postal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(6, $notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(7, $celphone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(8, $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(9, $specify, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(10, $reference, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->bindParam(11, $sign, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pst->execute();
$pst->closeCursor();
$pst = null;
```

Lo que sucede es que al momento de ejecutarlo, el servidor me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

> "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Carrito/actionphp/refreshDataSale.php:37"

Quería saber si alguien me podría ayudar.

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo la sentencia preparada con `$pst = $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`, quita la asignación para que quede `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` y ya debe funcionar.

Comment: @Triby Tu respuesta me ayudó a solucionar ese error, sin embargo ahora me aparecia que el SQLSTATE IM001 no lo soportaba o algo así, y quitando esa linea de código empezó a funcionar bien, entonces mi pregunta, es importante esa linea de código o lo puedo dejar sin ella? (Uso los PDO para evitar injecciones SQL)

Comment: Eso quiere decir que tu controlador de acceso a base de datos no soporta simulación de sentencias preparadas, con esa línea las estás desactivando y, por tanto, tienes el error. Resumen: Olvídate de esa línea. :-)

Comment: Vale, pero eso no significa que perderá el poder de evitar las sql injections?

Comment: No, porque está simulando sentencias preparadas y escapando los datos.